# Difference between aliasing,deep copy ,shallow copy pertaining to numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, deep-copy, shallow-copy

```
from numpy import *
arr1=array([1,2,3])
arr2=arr1 #aliasing
arr3=arr1.view() #shallow copy
arr4=arr1.copy() #deep copy
id(arr1) #120638624
id(arr2) #120638624
id(arr3) #120639004
id(arr4) #123894390
```

I know about shallow copy and deep copy as in C,C++ but what is it which is happening in python?

Look the c++ code . is it the same happen?

```
int main()
{
     int arr[]={1,2,3};
     int (&a)[3]=arr;//aliasing
     int* b=arr;// shallow copy
     int c[3];//deep copy
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            c[i]=arr[i];
 }
```

Comment: A view is distinct from a copy. The notion of deep copy vs shallow copy isn't really relevant for most use-cases of `numpy.ndarray` objects, unless you are using `object` dtype. Generally, you are more worried about whether something is a view vs a copy.

Comment: If you wrote code like your for-loop in Python it would only create a shallow copy. You should learn about Python's semantics on it's own terms: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html  Variables/names work very differently than in C++, although, it is much simpler, but it is different

Answer (score 0):

You have aliasing and deep copy right (though copying array values in a `for`-loop is not usually considered a good way to do it).

On the other hand, a Numpy `view` is not a pointer. It's a much heavier duty thing, and a proper object instance in it's own right. Conceptually, it's the closest thing to an actual pointer-to-array that exists in Python (though the semantics are of course different), and can fulfill some of the same roles in your code. A view will never be as performant as a raw pointer, since the view needs to carry around a set of data, such as shape and strides, that may be different from that of its "parent" array.

On the other-other hand, both Numpy arrays and views wrap the [`__array_interface__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.interface.html), which in turn wraps a pointer to the underlying buffer that holds the actual data. So when you make a new view of an array, you do end up making a proper shallow copy of the underlying data, since you  make a copy of the pointer to that data (albeit through several layers of wrapping and indirection).

Comment: It's not really like a pointer. A view is just a distinct *object* which uses the same underlying *primitive buffer* shared by potentially other numpy arrays

Comment: It's true, of course, that views and pointers are fundamentally nothing alike. However, they do fulfill some of the same roles, and views are ultimately implemented by wrapping a pointer to the data of the array onto which they look (via their `__array_interface__`).

Comment: Sure, but the concept of a view in *Python* extends to things like `dict` objects, or any user-defined class really, could be a *view* of another object, and Python *doesn't have pointers*, but the semantics of Python is essentially like having pointers everywhere that get de-reference automagically when you would want them to be.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, the numpy documentation talks about the `__array_interface__['data'][0]` as a `pointer`, "A 2-tuple whose first argument is an integer (a long integer if necessary) that points to the data-area storing the array contents. This pointer must point to the first element of data ..."  I do not recall any `view` terminology connected with `dict` or other Python classes.

Comment: @hpaulj I think this stuff from the [Py3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) is what he's talking about: `The objects returned by dict.keys(), dict.values() and dict.items() are view objects`. In terms of pedigree, concept, and implementation, I do think they're pretty distinct from Numpy views (aside from the name).